# ¿Como guardar varios Objetos en una misma posición en un ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

es decir si yo tengo

```
Persona p1= new Persona("123", "Dave", "Grohl");
Persona p2= new Persona("1234", "kurt", "Cobain");
Arraypersona.add(p1);
```

y en la misma posiciones añadir el "p2"
por ejemplo p1 esta en la posicion 1 y p2 quiero que este en la posicion 1
asi tener 2 objetos en un solo ArrayList no en 2 posiciones

```
Arraypersona.add(p1);
Arraypersona.add(p2);
```

Comment: Que lenguaje de programación es? Java? C++? Javascript?

Comment: Directamente es imposible, no puedes tener 2 objetos en una unica posición. Tendras que usar un ArrayList dentro de otro ArrayList

Comment: si ya sabes de antemano cuantos objetos serán puedes usar un array de en cada posicion de tu arraylsit ,y si no sabes cuantos objetos pueden ser puedes usar un arraylist.

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer creando un `ArrayList` que guarde un `Map`. Dentro de ese `Map` puedes poner varios objetos del tipo `Persona`.

```
    List<Map<Integer, Persona>> listPeoples = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<Integer, Persona> mapIndex0 = new HashMap<Integer, Persona>();
    mapIndex0.put(1,p1);
    mapIndex0.put(2,p2);
    listPeoples.add(0, mapIndex0);
```

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo completo:

<kbd>**[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](https://rextester.com/EVS73780)**</kbd>

```
    /*
        *Array que guardará en una misma posición 
        *un map con varios objetos del tipo Persona
    */
    List<Map<Integer, Persona>> listPeoples = new ArrayList<>();

    /*Objetos Persona*/
    Persona p1=new Persona("Pedro","Pérez");
    Persona p2=new Persona("María","Díaz");

    /*Mapa que se pondrá en la 1ª posición del array*/
    Map<Integer, Persona> mapIndex0 = new HashMap<Integer, Persona>();
    mapIndex0.put(1,p1);
    mapIndex0.put(2,p2);
    listPeoples.add(0, mapIndex0);

    /*Prueba de datos*/
    System.out.println(listPeoples.get(0).get(1).getFirstName());
    System.out.println(listPeoples.get(0).get(2).getFirstName());

    /*Más objetos para otra posición del array*/
    Persona p3=new Persona("Magdalena","Rodríguez");
    Persona p4=new Persona("Antonio","Moreno");
    Map<Integer, Persona> mapIndex1 = new HashMap<Integer, Persona>();
    mapIndex1.put(1,p3);
    mapIndex1.put(2,p4);
    listPeoples.add(1, mapIndex1);
    System.out.println(listPeoples.get(1).get(1).getFirstName());
    System.out.println(listPeoples.get(1).get(2).getFirstName());
```

---

**Salida:**

```
Pedro
María
Magdalena
Antonio
```

Comment: gracias me gusto mucho su lógica la aplicare.