# Array de Objetos en Java

Tags: java, array, hashmap

Buen día,

Estoy intentando imprimir este array en java, el value es un String

```
initCategories = [
               { key:'Territoriales', value: null},
               { key:'Zonas', value: null },
               { key:'Oficinas', value: null },
               { key:'Cargos', value: null },
               { key:'Funcionarios', value: null },
               { key:'Clientes', value: null }
        ]
```

He utilizado un `Hashmap<String,String>`, pero no he tenido éxito,

```
HashMap<String, String> response = new HashMap<String, String>();
            response.put("key","Territoriales");
            response.put("name", workPlaceDetail.getData().getZone().getTerritorial().getName());
            response.put("key","Zonas");
            response.put("name", workPlaceDetail.getData().getZone().getName());  
            response.put("key","Oficinas");
            response.put("name", workPlace);  
            response.put("key","Cargos");
            response.put("name", "null");
            response.put("key","Funcionarios");
            response.put("name", "null");
            response.put("key","Clientes");
            response.put("name", "null");
```

Comment: No se entiende muy bien, por un lado muestras un objeto llamado `initCategories` y por otro un `HashMap` que se llama `response`. ¿Qué es lo que quieres en sí? ¿Qué son esos dos objetos y cómo se relacionan? Un mapa no acepta `key` repetidas, veo que en response das a varios pares la `key` que se llama `key`... parece que estás confundiendo el sentido del primer valor del map, que es una llave identificativa, no es que tengas que poner la palabra `key` ahí. También se repite `name` varias veces... ¿?

Comment: si un mapa no acepta key repetidas. Cuál otra forma podría utilizar para crear un arreglo que tenga objetos repetidos con el mismo key? Muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: No entiendo muy bien qué es lo que quieres.  En un mapa puedes guardar objetos enteros, pero tendrían que ser todos del mismo tipo. Por ejemplo algo así: `HashMap<String, Persona> response = new HashMap<String, Persona>();` y ahí pondrías dentro **instancias** de `Persona` Ojo, dos objetos nunca son iguales en sí, son instancias diferentes... O no sé si lo que quieres es [algo como esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/218997/29967). Si es posible explica mejor lo que necesitas para poder ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que tu `HashMap` debería crearse así:

```
HashMap<String, String> response = new HashMap<String, String>();
            response.put("Territoriales", workPlaceDetail.getData().getZone().getTerritorial().getName());
            response.put("Zonas", workPlaceDetail.getData().getZone().getName());  
            response.put("Oficinas", workPlace);  
            response.put("Cargos", "null");
            response.put("Funcionarios", "null");
            response.put("Clientes", "null");
```

Realmente un `HashMap` sirve para guardar valores relacionados mediante una llave. El dato de la izquierda que pones en el `put` sería la llave, y el dato de la derecha sería el valor.

En la asignación de tu `HashMap` se nota un error de comprensión, queriendo asignar cada valor dos veces como valor.

Si creas el mapa como indicado arriba y lo lees así:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : response.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key: " + item.getKey() + " - Value: " + item.getValue());
}
```

Tendrás en pantalla algo parecido a esto:

```
Key: Oficinas - Value: Dato workPlace
Key: Zonas - Value: Dato Zonas
Key: Funcionarios - Value: null
Key: Clientes - Value: null
Key: Cargos - Value: null
Key: Territoriales - Value: Dato Territoriales
```